# how to puts value in each slot of the array

Tags: java, arrays, loops

How can i put a value into each slot of the array. Meaning i have:

```
String name[] = new name[50];
for (int i=0; int<=name; int++;){
    name[1] = "name 1";
    name[2] = 'name 2";       
}
```

This is what i have so far but i know that it is not right. I could make 50 different array and give name i could do `name[1] = new name["kevin"];` and so on and keeping that for all 50 people.But that so many lines of code.

so how do i give all 50 a name. and i need to do in one loop or something like that.

or can i do this:

`people[] people = new people[50];`

Comment: Do you want to initialize all the elements of the array with the same value or a different value for each element?

Comment: use `String[] name = new String[50];`

Answer (score 5):

If you want to assign a name to all of them according to the pattern *name index* you do it like this

```
for (int i = 0; i < name.length; i++) {
    name[i] = "name " +  (i + 1);
}
```

and by the way, initialize your array like this

```
String name[] = new String[50];
```

Comment: ArrayIndexOutOfBounds on i == 50

Answer (score 1):

open Scanner for input, Take name as input and then loop over 50 times

```
  // open Scanner for input
  Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);

  String name[] = new String[50];
  for (int i=0; i< name.length; i++){
      //take input
      System.out.println("Input");
      String input = keyboard.nextLine();
      name[i] = input;

  }
```